# Hausdorff Vs Uniform convergence

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $X$ a metric space, $K_{n}\subset X$ compact  and
 $f_{n}:K_{n}\longrightarrow K_{n}$ a continuous function, for each $n\geq 1$.

It is easy to prove that if $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ uniformly, then $d_{H}(X,K_{n})\rightarrow 0$, $d_{H}$ being the Hausdorff distance. But, Under that conditions we can state the reciprocal? That is, if $d_{H}(X,K_{n})\rightarrow 0$, Under that conditions can we ensure the existence of $f:X\longrightarrow X$ such that $f_{n}\rightarrow f$?

Many thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: See [Difference between uniform and Hausdorff convergence of curves in $\mathbb{R}^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2113200/difference-between-uniform-and-hausdorff-convergence-of-curves-in-mathbbr2), especially the pointers I give in my comment there.

Comment: Thanks. The example is good, and clearly shows that Hausdorff convergence does not imply uniform convergence. The references seem not be available to download for free.

Comment: I thought that quite a few of Gerald Beer's papers were freely available, so this may be due to the country you're in (your profile doesn't say where you live). For example, [*On uniform convergence of continuous functions and topological convergence of sets*](https://cms.math.ca/10.4153/CMB-1983-069-6) AND [*Metric spaces on which continuous functions are uniformly continuous and Hausdorff distance*](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1985-095-04/S0002-9939-1985-0810180-3/) appear to be freely available. **(continued)**

Comment: Both Beer and [Sendov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blagovest_Sendov) are fairly well known, so [searches like this](https://www.google.com/search?q=math+Sendov+Hausdorff+uniform) should lead you to a lot of things, as well as googling the titles of the two Beer papers I gave above.

Comment: Thanks Dave L. Renfro. The above papers are free for download :)